# Will not upsert on external ID (claims a MISSING_ARGUMENT)

Tags: apex, upsert, externalid

I am upserting a list a list and it claims the external ID is missing. It is not missing as shown below.

I have broken my big upsert into a for loop to track the problem. I have played around with a few things but no luck

```
for(Toggl_Time_Entry__c eachTE : timeEntries){

         Schema.SObjectField f = Toggl_Time_Entry__c.Fields.Toggl_ID__c;
         Database.UpsertResult  cr = Database.upsert(eachTE , f, false);  
}
```

Here is an extract from my debug logs (in an email). Notice that they all have Toggl_ID__c and then you get to the last line and it fails claiming that it is not specified.

```
 - Toggl_Time_Entry__c:{Toggl_ID__c=759879894, Name=Name, Timer_Start__c=2017-12-21 20:07:27, Toggl_Updated__c=2017-12-21 20:16:39, Duration__c=0.152222222222222222222222222222222}
 - Database.UpsertResult[getErrors=();getId=a0g0q000000IgZGAA0;isCreated=false;isSuccess=true;]
 - Toggl_Time_Entry__c:{Toggl_ID__c=759873409, Name=Name, Timer_Start__c=2017-12-21 19:57:33, Toggl_Updated__c=2017-12-21 22:08:52, Duration__c=2.18888888888888888888888888888888}
 - Database.UpsertResult[getErrors=();getId=a0g0q000000IgZHAA0;isCreated=false;isSuccess=true;]
 - Toggl_Time_Entry__c:{Toggl_ID__c=759870523, Name=Name, Timer_Start__c=2017-12-21 19:43:02, Toggl_Updated__c=2017-12-21 19:57:27, Duration__c=0.233333333333333333333333333333333}
 - Database.UpsertResult[getErrors=(Database.Error[getFields=();getMessage=Toggl_ID__c not specified;getStatusCode=MISSING_ARGUMENT;]);getId=null;isCreated=false;isSuccess=false;]
 - Toggl_Time_Entry__c:{Toggl_ID__c=759248572, Name=Name, Timer_Start__c=2017-12-21 06:55:53, Toggl_Updated__c=2017-12-21 08:43:06, Duration__c=1.78722222222222222222222222222222}
 - Database.UpsertResult[getErrors=();getId=a0g0q000000IgZIAA0;isCreated=false;isSuccess=true;]
 - Toggl_Time_Entry__c:{Toggl_ID__c=759148965, Name=Name, Timer_Start__c=2017-12-21 00:50:14, Toggl_Updated__c=2017-12-21 04:13:42, Duration__c=3.39055555555555555555555555555555}
 - Database.UpsertResult[getErrors=();getId=a0g0q000000IgZJAA0;isCreated=false;isSuccess=true;]
 - Toggl_Time_Entry__c:{Toggl_ID__c=759148497, Name=Name, Timer_Start__c=2017-12-21 00:48:47, Toggl_Updated__c=2017-12-21 00:50:13, Duration__c=0.0240025}
 - Database.UpsertResult[getErrors=();getId=a0g0q000000IgZKAA0;isCreated=false;isSuccess=true;]
 - Toggl_Time_Entry__c:{Toggl_ID__c=759131187, Name=Name, Timer_Start__c=2017-12-21 00:00:41, Toggl_Updated__c=2017-12-21 00:02:23, Duration__c=0.0283333333333333333333333333333333}
 - Database.UpsertResult[getErrors=(Database.Error[getFields=();getMessage=Toggl_ID__c not specified;getStatusCode=MISSING_ARGUMENT;]);getId=null;isCreated=false;isSuccess=false;]
```

Comment: DML statement in `for` loop is not recommended. From this piece of code it's difficult to understand what's the issue is in code

Comment: I know there sholdn't be a DML statement in a loop. I was trying to see which record was breaking the upsert.  I'm stumped on why the last one fails.

Comment: Have you tried doing the upsert bulkfully? Does it throw the same error?

Comment: Is `thisTE` supposed to be `eachTE`?

Comment: @DanielHowell Add an assertion before the upsert is attempted.
`System.assertNotEquals(null, eachTE);` Also, are there any triggers at play here? Check the Apex debug log.

Comment: The eachTE was a typo on copying. You can see that it's not null as it is printed in the logs on the line above. it would print null if null.  No triggers on this object.

Comment: What about Workflow Rules? Process Builder? Any way the field could have been cleared would bear verification here (not just `Apex Triggers`).

Comment: It's brand new object in a sandbox. Nothing is on it at all. Doesn't link to anything.

Comment: I turned off all triggers and process builders and workflows in the entire org. It's nothing to do with that as expected.

Comment: So the other ones are all updates. Does 759131187 have a match? Would it be the first insert? If so, any required fields that could be missing?

Comment: I'll all inserted into an empty table. I will be checking all of the other objects as it must be a simliar sounding field or something. This doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Can you post *all* of your code? Something that we can execute in the Developer Console to see the behaviour (assuming we create the custom object in an org). I know it seems silly, but what you're seeing based on the code you posted is totally baffling. So maybe the problem is elsewhere (how you construct the timeEntries list?). At least if we can run the code, we can test theories on it.

Comment: Do you have any Validation Rules on Toggl_Time_Entry__c?